# footer doesn't stretch full width - no margins. Weird

Tags: css, width

Footer is width: 100%. Only parent is Body and that's width: 100% with 0 margins. Why are there margins on either side? The only element with margins is above footer, but shouldn't be effecting it. URL-REMOVED. CLOSED.

Answer (score 3):

Add `padding: 0` to your body element.

Comment: Stupid. I stared at this for hours.

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Comment: Gonna remove this due to work in process, but thank you for the prompt answer!

Comment: Removing questions after you get an answer is pretty bad form on a site like SO.  Just sayin..

Comment: I just removed the URL. All good. Thanks guys. I'll accept your answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

`body` has a horizontal padding of 15 pixels.